# NextJS Webpack - Generate an executable public JS file

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am trying to get a simple example running where I can create a "widget" inside my NextJS application, making use of Zoid and then have this load in a third party website.

I have managed to get a JS file to export using webpack by adding the following to my next.config.js

```
webpack: function (webpackConfig) {
    const originalEntry = webpackConfig.entry;

    webpackConfig.entry = async () => {
      const entries = await originalEntry();

      return {
        ...entries,
        "login-widget": {
          import: "./src/widgets/login-widget.js",
          dependOn: undefined,
        },
      };
    };

    return webpackConfig;
  },
```

This login-widget.js file is super simple for now and just contains a console.log.

The generated webpack file is something like the below, bits redacted:

```
(self["webpackChunk_N_E"] = self["webpackChunk_N_E"] || []).push([["login-widget"],{
    (function(module, __unused_webpack_exports, __webpack_require__) {
        eval(__webpack_require__.ts("console.log('Test 123');\n\n;\n 
    })
});
```

But when I import the generated script in to a static HTML page, the console.log doesn't run which is I assume being caused by the webpack bundle.

How do I go about making this webpack generated JS file executable when imported as as script on a site?

Thanks